# How I can access length of string in Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

How can I access using length of strings(ex.len function) in Pandas Series

How to access 'eee'(3 char) exclude index accessing

```
test=pd.Series(['aaaa','bbbb','cccc','dddd','eee'])

==> 4 eee
```

Comment: Use iloc and -1 to get last item. `test.iloc[-1]`

Comment: thanks but sometimes I am not sure index of values

Comment: What is the link between the length and indexing?? Do you want to have only strings with 3 chars?

Answer (score 4):

What you want is unclear.

To get the length of each string use [`str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html):

```
test.str.len()
```

output:

```
0    4
1    4
2    4
3    4
4    3
dtype: int64
```

To select the strings with 3 characters use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
test[test.str.len().eq(3)]
```

output:

```
4    eee
dtype: object
```